# Re-ordering layers before exporting to web map?

Tags: qgis2web

I have two layers and two groups that need to be listed above a google hybrid layer.  When I start qgis2web it reorders the layers placing the two groups (roads and places) under the google hybrid layer...thus obscuring the two groups.  How do I reorder the layers to place the google hybrid layer on the bottom before exporting?

Comment: I'm afraid layer groups simply aren't well supported in qgis2web. If removing groups completely is an option, I'd consider that. Otherwise, I'm afraid it's just something we have to live with until it can be solved with development of the plugin: https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/issues/175

Answer (score 1):

I put the google hybrid in a group and that sort of solved the issue.  The problem is the roads and places etc. do not seem to be responding well to being in groups when exported with qgis2web.  Most labels are not visible, etc.  Will keep trying.  May have to remove all the layers from the groups.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with the search function, and what did it for me was adjusting the pane Z index. So basically the layers i wanted at the "bottom" i made sure they had a lower Z index value than the layers at the top (e.g. i have layers 1,2 and 3, and want them in that order so id go something like this:
1 = 200
2 = 201
3 = 400)
Not sure if that will help, but worth a shot! good luck